# GridSplitter Not present

Tags: wpf

I use this in code behind to test how to add a grid splitter programmatically. (I know, don't use code behind - But this is one of those rare cases I need to. (I think))

```
public partial class ContainerView : Window, IContainerView
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ContainerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetUp();
    }

    public void SetUp()
    {
        _grid = new Grid();

        //Single column/single row
        _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        _grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        _grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        var button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Btn 1";
        button1.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        Grid.SetRow(button1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(button1, 0);

        var button2 = new Button();
        button2.Content = "Btn 2";
        button2.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        Grid.SetRow(button2, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(button2, 2);

        _grid.Children.Add(button1);
        _grid.Children.Add(button2);

        var splitterV = new GridSplitter();
        Grid.SetRowSpan(splitterV, _grid.RowDefinitions.Count);
        splitterV.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        splitterV.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        splitterV.ShowsPreview = true;
        splitterV.Background = Brushes.Black;
        Width = 5;

        _grid.Children.Add(splitterV);
        Grid.SetColumn(splitterV, 1);

        Content = _grid;
    }
```

I can see the two buttons, but the middle column is empty. The `GridSplitter` is not shown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct but you are setting Window's width instead of GridSpitter's width & also you have to give it's ResizeBehaviour.

Instead of this :

```
Width = 5;
```

Set GridSpitter's Width & It's ResizeBehavior   as :

```
splitterV.ResizeBehavior = GridResizeBehavior.PreviousAndNext;
splitterV.Width = 5;
```

Comment: I want to cry. Thanks.